# How to echo data selected from the database one at a time?

Tags: php, mysqli

Here I select all of the topics and then display all of the rows at once with the 'echo $categories'. I would like to do it so echo $categories will echo the first row of data, then if I type echo $categories again it will echo the second row of data etc. Any idea on how I can do this? Thanks

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($DBconnect, "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY category_title ASC");
$categories = "";

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['category_title'];
        $description = $row['category_description'];
        $categories .= "<br><a href='view_category.php?cid=" . $id . "'>" . $title . " </a>- " . $description . "</a>";
    }
}

echo $categories;

?>
```

Comment: you're doing `.=`, so you're building up a string inside the loop. if you don't want that, then put the echo inside the loop: `echo '<br>.....';`

Comment: Be more specific. I assume you want to add code to display the items within the categories but if thats the case _say so_ it makes the question more understandable if we can see a reason for your asking how to do something as simple as this. Otherwise people just look at the question and are not sure what context you are trying to change it in

Answer (score 1):

Declare the array categories before the loop

```
var $categories = array();
```

Then, inside the loop add the html string with all the data to the array categories

```
$categories[] = "<br><a href='view_category.php?cid=".$id."'>".$title." </a>- ".$description."</a>";
```

And later to access the category that you want just do this:

```
echo $categories[0];
echo $categories[1];
```

Etc...

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly you could try the following, instead of:

```
$categories = "";
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['category_title'];
        $description = $row['category_description'];
        $categories .= "<br><a href='view_category.php?cid=".$id."'>".$title." </a>- ".$description."</a>";
   }
 }
 echo $categories
```

Becasue `$categories .=` will be added to `$categories = ''` it will build a string. This is then all echoed out once in `echo $categories.` So waht you can do is the following. It will echo each `categorie`

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $id = $row['id'];
     $title = $row['category_title'];
     $description = $row['category_description'];
     echo "<a href='view_category.php?cid=".$id."'>".$title." </a>- ".$description."</a><br>";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You  cannot do it this way. You cannot know beforehand how many categories you have, so, you cannot write all these echos manually. To echo your data from database, a loop is the only proper way.